# Are HTML allowed inside HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, lets say you have something like this:

```
<div data-object="{'str': '<h1>This is a nice headline</h1>'}"></div>
```

Is this allowed in HTML5 and will it render properly in all browsers?

Edit: 
With properly I mean that the browser will ignore and NOT render the H1 in any way ;)

Comment: have you tried it.???

Comment: Maybe if you encode it...

Comment: **Attributes are not rendered** so...no, it won't be. Moreover **attributes value must follow same rules as _plain_ text** (so "<" must be replaced with &lt; and so on...)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's allowed as long as it's quoted correctly.

Will it render? The H1 element? No - because it's not an element, it's just a bit of text inside an attribute of the div element.

Comment: With properly I mean that the browser will ignore and NOT render the H1 in any way ;)

Comment: As symcbean said, it's *not* an element, it doesn't belong to the DOM as an H1 element, it's just text inside an attribute. It won't get interpreted, much less display.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, browsers won't render any HTML tags inside attributes. This is pretty much common when you want to move the element later so it would show up. The only problem is that this is not a way to go as this does not create an element in DOM, thus, it will be much slower.

Try to find a way or ask for an alternative/better way to reuse the element which is hidden when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's allowed and possible, but to make it work you have to make it valid JSON by using double quotes:

```
<div data-object='{"str": "<h1>This is a nice headline</h1>"}'></div>
```

Now to parse it just have: (jQuery will parse it to JSON all by itself)

```
var element = $("div").eq(0);
var rawData = element.data("object");
var rawHTML = rawData["str"];
$(rawHTML).appendTo("body");
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/McKEU/).